# JQuery adiciona "selected" em um option

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<select id="billing">
    <option value="485">Acre</option>
    <option value="486">Amapá</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Quando o usuário digita o CEP, o sistema automaticamente busca o endereço e insere os dados no formulário. Porém, preciso que esse JQuery localize o value do option e inclua selected="selected".
Obrigado pela força.

Comment: Não é bem assim que funciona as coisas... basta fazer um `document.getElementById('billing').value = 486`, por exemplo

Answer (score 1):

Não tendo o resto do código, é difícil dar um exemplo funcional, mas isso deve fazer o que você precisa: `$('#billing').val(seuValor);`

```js
function testar(){
  $('#billing').val('485');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="billing">
    <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Estado</option>
    <option value="485">Acre</option>
    <option value="486">Amapá</option>
</select>
<button onclick="testar()">Clique me</button>
```

Comment: Acrescentei um exemplo funcional, espero que não se importe :)

Comment: Obrigado @MarceloBoni pela edição, ficou bem melhor assim :)